# How to join lists of dataframe that were split using plyr function

Tags: r, plyr

I have used the **strip_splits(df)** function provided by the **plyr** package to obtain a list of data frames.  I now want to join the list of data frames together and add back in the variables used to split them.  The documentation highlighted below leads me to believe this should be possible, however I can't find the appropriate function.

> This is useful when you want to perform some operation to every column in the data frame, except the variables that you have used for splitting. These variables will be automatically added back on to the result when combining all results together.

Example:

```
dfSplit <- dlply(mtcars, c("vs", "am"), strip_splits)
df <- dfSplit[[1]]
score <- function(df) {
  df$score <- apply(apply(df, 2, scale), 1, mean, na.rm = TRUE)
  return(df)
}
dfSplit <- lapply(dfSplit, score)
```

How do I combine data frames in the list *dfSplit* together again?

Edit: The combined data frame should have the columns *vs* and *am*

Answer (score 3):

Using `bind_rows()` from `dplyr`:

```
library(dplyr)
bind_rows(dfSplit)
```

Or using base R:

```
do.call(rbind, dfSplit)
```

Which gives:

```
#Source: local data frame [32 x 10]
#
#    mpg cyl  disp  hp drat    wt  qsec gear carb       score
#1  18.7   8 360.0 175 3.15 3.440 17.02    3    2 -0.18850120
#2  14.3   8 360.0 245 3.21 3.570 15.84    3    4  0.05315376
#3  16.4   8 275.8 180 3.07 4.070 17.40    3    3 -0.15909455
#4  17.3   8 275.8 180 3.07 3.730 17.60    3    3 -0.14033030
#5  15.2   8 275.8 180 3.07 3.780 18.00    3    3 -0.16788329
#6  10.4   8 472.0 205 2.93 5.250 17.98    3    4  0.42384103
#7  10.4   8 460.0 215 3.00 5.424 17.82    3    4  0.49006288
#8  14.7   8 440.0 230 3.23 5.345 17.42    3    4  0.79264565
#9  15.5   8 318.0 150 2.76 3.520 16.87    3    2 -0.79767163
#10 15.2   8 304.0 150 3.15 3.435 17.30    3    2 -0.53819495
#..  ... ...   ... ...  ...   ...   ...  ...  ...         ...
```

Answer (score 3):

You can also use `rbindlist` from `data.table` package:

```
library(data.table)
rbindlist(dfSplit)
```

Answer (score 0):

I have since found the plyr function ldply which gives

```
.id  mpg cyl  disp  hp drat    wt  qsec gear carb       score
1  0.0 18.7   8 360.0 175 3.15 3.440 17.02    3    2 -0.18850120
2  0.0 14.3   8 360.0 245 3.21 3.570 15.84    3    4  0.05315376
3  0.0 16.4   8 275.8 180 3.07 4.070 17.40    3    3 -0.15909455
4  0.0 17.3   8 275.8 180 3.07 3.730 17.60    3    3 -0.14033030
5  0.0 15.2   8 275.8 180 3.07 3.780 18.00    3    3 -0.16788329
```

however the documentation leads me to believe that there should be a function which gives the data frame with columns vs and am (rather than .id)